# reading a portion of file to a buffer using fread

Tags: c, pointers, fread

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

I have a file which I need to copy last n bytes to an array.

```
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    size_t result = fread(buffer,sizeof(char)*n,1,outptr);
```

The value of result is 0.

Everything up till here in my code works right( I have checked all the values with gdb). I am freeing the buffer too after some lines.

n is userinputted. The output ptr is used as

```
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile,"w")
```

//The outfile name is also user inputted and is checked to make sure it is a bmp file.

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? How is `n` calculated? How is `outptr` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to read from a file you have opened in write mode.

Change:

```
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile,"w");
```

to:

```
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile,"r"); /* Use "rb", not "r", if 'outfile' is binary. */
```

Answer (score 1):

`size_t result = fread(buffer, n, 1, outptr);` should fine.

OTOH, is the file that you're working on is empty?

Please make sure that `fopen()` was successful and also check whether `malloc()` was successful!

On a completely different note, `sizeof()` and `fread()` returns `size_t` and that should be cast to `int`.